# Visual Studio не видит классы Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, классы

После переустоновки vs перестал видеть классы юнити. Не знаю на всех форумах перелазил толком ответа не нашёл. Все библиотеки using есть. А вот класс MonoBehaviour не подсвечивается и подсказок по синтаксису Unity не наблюдаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Units : MonoBehaviour {
public new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
public Animator anim;
public int lifes;

public int Lives
{
    get { return lifes; }
    set { lifes = value; }
}
protected virtual void ReceiveDamage ()
{
    Die();
}
protected virtual void Die ()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в референсах что?

Comment: если скажете куда зайти скажу
Не так давно в программировании

Comment: вроде бы оно, если не ошибаюсь

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Просто укажите редактора для кода в настройках Unity.

[image: preference screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Ребята, все просто, проверить конечно надо что за IDE установлена, но такое бывает часто после обновления. Делаем по картинке и перезапускаем Юньку и ВС Студию ) [image: Все гениальное просто! =P]

Answer (score 2):

Закрой Unity и VisualStudio
В папке, где находится твой проект удали все файлы кроме Assets и ProjectSettings.
Открой в Unity и  с него попробуй открыть скрипт в VS.
Если, всё ещё не видит, попробуй открыть VS-проект с директории, где проект, там должен быть файл YourProjectName.sln

Answer (score 1):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity
Вдруг кому пригодиться, как мне. Что именно смотреть:
Open up Unity Preferences, External Tools, then browse for the Visual Studio Code executable as External Script Editor. Т.е. Edit/Preferences.../External tools/External Script Editor > Выбрать нужный.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Папка проекта]

Такая же проблема была, VisulStudio не видела классов и не подключалась к Юнити, вот этот файл (решение), портило всё, удалил его, при выходе из VS указал не сохронять "Solucion", зашёл в Юнити, открыл скрипт через неё и всё вернулось на круги своя.)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего не установлен компонент разработка игр на Unity.

[image: 1]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).