unity , не показываются классы в visual studio
не работал canvas, друг сказал попробовать скинуть на дефолт проект, это когда все сбрасывается в unity а именно плагины и настройки, после сброса перестали работать подсказки да и вообще все что связанно с кодом и юнити, искал все в интернете и сразу скажу что в визуал студио установлена разработка юнити, и в preferences подключена visual studio, как вернут подсказки обратно?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846472/visual-studio-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-unity возможный дубликат вопроса

Посидев и облазив интернет я все же нашел ответ, при сбросе плагинов в юнити также там есть стандартные плагины и если Visual Studio подключена к Unity а также включены подсказки, всему виной отсутствие 2 плагинов Visual Studio Editor а также Visual Studio Editor code, поэтому нцжно зайти в Packet Manager в юнити, и установить данные плагины
